# Magento Multiselect attribute not saving

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Magento 1.9.x

I have two attribute sets. Both sets have a lot of the same custom attributes. However, I have a multi-select attribute that will save values if its a product under one attribute set but if I have a product under a different attribute set that same value area will not save.